# How to twitter status in Unicode by using Twitter's API `status/update_with_media`?

Tags: twitter

I need to update status and image to Twitter, by using the new API `status/update_with_media`, I can update status (in ASCII characters) with image to Twitter, but when the status contains Unicode characters, for example, the Chinese `通`, its UTF-8 encode is `%E9%80%9A`, I encoded the string into UTF-8 just like plain update, and the POST body looks like that:

```
------------------------------d67b3e07c45e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="status"

%E9%80%9A
------------------------------d67b3e07c45e--
```

and the update success, but the Chinese `通` display as the original `%E9%80%9A`, how to make it displayed as the Chinese `通`? Does it need to add more directives to denote the character set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:

Do **NOT** encode your Unicode into URL-encoded while using the API status/update_with_media, include those `!@#$%^&*()-+\` and so on, just encode them in UTF-8, and past them as the original, Twitter can read and display them OK.